# Changing NSLayoutConstraint height constant causes UIScrollView to jump

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a series of cells laid out vertically. The `contentSize` of the scroll view is determined by the cell's `NSLayoutConstraints`. One of the cells has a `UICollectionView` which allows adding email addresses -- like the "To:" field in Mail. Initially, if the user taps in this field, the scroll view is moved so the cell is at the top of the scroll view and the keyboard comes into view. As email addresses are added the height of the cell must grow, so a layout constraint constant on the cell is adjusted to the new height.

The problem is, adjusting this constraint causes the scroll view to suddenly scroll to top. Instead, I want it to just grow the cell but keep the `contentOffset` the same.

Comment: I've tried disabling `scrollEnabled` and `scrollsToTop` before making the height change and intercepting `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop`. None of these helped. The OS seems to just ignore these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution. Set a boolean when the field in question is being edited and if the scroll view moves, then immediately reset the content offset to the field's y position. It seems that `scrollViewDidScroll` is the only delegate method that gets called.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.editingGuests) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.guestsCell.frame.origin.y);
    }
}
```

From my tests this causes no visual problems.